# AWS-GLUE encoding utf-8

Tags: python, utf-8, aws-glue

I have a problem when I submit a job in glue. My data in s3 contain ñ and accents, this causes that the job fails: `unable to parse fail s3://...`
If i edit my job with the python header: 
`# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` the jobs fail too.
Any idea?
Thank you beforehand.

Comment: add a code and data snippet (a cuople of strings) it is unclear what is going on. Btw, try to read this with spark directly from s3 path it can be a workaround, but bookmarks will not work in that case.

Comment: I have the same issue and am using the workaround of removing the characters.  You could also encode them before sending them to glue.  I, unfortunately, haven't figured out a better solution yet.

Comment: Link to AWS help request ... https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=826599